# Using FreeRTOS with XC8 compiler

Tags: c, freertos

I'm trying to setup FreeRTOS with XC8 compiler with no success. I've searched over internet but there is not much information about it. I am using a PIC18F46K80 so I can't use C18 because it's not supported.

I am trying to compile this minimal program:

```
#include <p18f46k80.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <FreeRTOS.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I have included the corresponding paths to the compiler:

[image]

And the error I'm getting is this:

> FreeRTOS/Source/include\timers.h:71: error: (103) #error: "include
>   FreeRTOS.h must appear in source files before include timers.h"
>
> FreeRTOS/Source/include\task.h:71: error: (103) #error: "include
>   FreeRTOS.h must appear in source files before include task.h"

You can clearly see I'm including `FreeRTOS.h`. I tried for example in `timers.h` to manually add the `#define` here:

```
#ifndef INC_FREERTOS_H
    #error "include FreeRTOS.h must appear in source files before include timers.h"
#endif
```

The error gets away but I get a lot of new errors. Is not possible to use FreeRTOS with XC8? Are there any other free RTOS available for XC8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with C18 but the newest versions of FreeRTOS doesn't compile anymore. Due to fragmented architecture on PIC18 FreeRTOS is not supporting them anymore, neither the community, so if you want to use RTOS better to try with PIC24 or higher or try some simpler RTOS designed only for PIC18!